# Why does getAttribute('href') return the full URL when used with reduce?

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have a list of anchors with internal IDs and I want to select all targets using `.querySelectorAll()` like:

```
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('#target-1, #target-2, …')
```

---

To prepare this query I used `reduce`:

```
anchors.reduce((previous, current, index) =>
    index === 0 ?
        current.getAttribute('href') :
        previous + ', ' + current.getAttribute('href')
)
```

---

This almost works, but there's a strange issue and the result looks like this:

```
https://full-url.com/#target-1, #target-2, #target-3
```

---

When I only run:

```
targets[0].getAttribute('href')
```

… it returns the expected result:

```
target-1
```

---

You can try it yourself:

```js
const anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));

console.log(anchors[0].getAttribute('href'));

console.log(anchors.reduce((previous, current, index) => index === 0 ? current.getAttribute('href') : previous + ', ' + current.getAttribute('href')));
```

```html
<a href="#target-1"></a>
<a href="#target-2"></a>
<a href="#target-3"></a>
```

---

This happens at least in Chrome, Safari and Firefox on macOS.

Why is the full URL prepended to the first element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters) requires an initial value to be passed. Try passing the empty string:

```js
const anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));
const first = anchors[0].getAttribute('href');
const all = anchors.reduce((previous, current, index) => index === 0 ? current.getAttribute('href') : previous + ', ' + current.getAttribute('href'), "");

/* The first 'href' value. */
console.log(first);

/* All 'href' values. */
console.log(all);

/* When concatenating an <a> element with a string, a link is returned. */
console.log(anchors[0] + "");
```

```html
<a href="#target-1"></a>
<a href="#target-2"></a>
<a href="#target-3"></a>
```

If you don't pass an initial value, the first element of the array is used. Since the elements in your array are `<a>` elements, the entire URL is prepended, because, when you concatenate an anchor element with a string, the anchor element is translated to an actual link ([as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement#Methods)).

Comment: I agree they have to do it, but an explanation on what happens might be a good add.

Comment: Okay, but why does it seem to use the full URL as an initial value?

Comment: Ah I see - I did miss the inital value. Also good explanation, why the default value doesn't evaluate to `''`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the code slightly, it becomes less code and works. You do not have to use `reduce` for this. This way you not to fiddle with the initial and accumulated value, just transform the list anchors into a list of there `href`s
 and join that…

```js
const anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));

const str = anchors.map(a => a.getAttribute('href')).join(',');
console.log(str);
```

```html
<a href="#target-1"></a>
<a href="#target-2"></a>
<a href="#target-3"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with this code at it's easier to maintain. :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass empty string as initial value to the call back function:

```js
let anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));

 anchors = anchors.reduce((previous, current, index) => index === 0 ? current.getAttribute('href') : previous + ', ' + current.getAttribute('href'),"");
 console.log(anchors)
```

```html
<a href="#target-1"></a>
<a href="#target-2"></a>
<a href="#target-3"></a>
```

Comment: I agree they have to do it, but an explanation on what happens might be a good add.

Answer (score 1):

Why it happens is because the initialValue in the reduce is optional, if not passed, it takes the first index of the array as the initial value. So, if you log the first index and toString it, you'll see the full url along with the hash. Try

```
console.log(anchors[0].toString())
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) what the spec says:

> Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

For correct code, please see's [Angel's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52202045/2206733)